# How to convert date format with T format in c#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a date format as shown below `2021-02-11T13:00:00+04:00` which i need to get in following format `11-FEB-20 01.00.00.000000000 PM`.How can i achieve it ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: [Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0) it to `DateTime`, then `ToString` with the desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `Parse` form existing format into `DateTime` and then format it into `String` with the desired format string:

```
  string source = "2021-02-11T13:00:00+04:00";

  string result = DateTime
    .Parse(source)
    .ToString("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff'00' tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToUpper();
```

Please, note

- `ToUpper()` since we want `FEB`, not `Feb`.
- `fffffff'00'` - we can't provide **9**, but **7** digits after the decimal point, so we have to append two zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Parse and then format according to [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2021-02-11T13:00:00+04:00");
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yy"));
```